# A javascript function triggered by onblur gives an alert, but doesn't change innerHTML of an element

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, onblur

I wrote a function that sets the innerHTML of a span with the id "mail_not_valid" to "that doesn't seem right" when the user tries to submit an invalid e-mail address. Works fine. Another function clears the input field and is triggered by onfocus. The third function is triggered by onblur and resets the input field to its original value when the user didn't enter anything. Now here is the problem: if the user clicks on the field (->cleared), enters an invalid e-mail (->span shows up) and then just deletes his entry and leaves the form, the span is still there.

Now when I replace document.getElementById("mail_not_valid").innerHTML = ""; with an alert, the alert does show up. Changing the innerHTML does not work, though.

EDIT: I'm an idiot, it can't work if the user already wrote something: if (!(feld.value))

```
<input onblur="OnBlurCondition (this, 'subscribe to the e-mail newsletter')">

<script language="javascript">
function OnBlurCondition (feld, inhalt) {
        if (!(feld.value)){
                feld.value = inhalt;
                if (document.getElementById("mail_not_valid").innerHTML == "that doesn't seem right."){
                    document.getElementById("mail_not_valid").innerHTML = "";
                }   
        }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure if it's just a typo, but in your example you are using a comparison operator (`==`) rather than an assignment operator (`=`).

Comment: Does the HTML actually contain an element with id `mail_not_valid`? Any errors in the console?

Comment: have you tried alerting or using console.log( document.getElementById("mail_not_valid").innerHTML to make sure that it equals what you have for the comparison? In that scenario if you have whitespace/linebreaks etc it will throw off the comparison unless they match exactly.

Comment: Ah yeah there scott got it haha nice catch man I dunno how I missed that :P He's right. Change == to = on that line and it will probably work lol

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo. Should be this:

```
if (document.getElementById("mail_not_valid").innerHTML == "that doesn't seem right."){
    document.getElementById("mail_not_valid").innerHTML = "";
}
```

Note the single equal sign.

Also, don't copy/paste code. Use decent editor/IDE. Copy/paste is evil! :)

Comment: I already +1, but I would give another if I could for the Copy/Paste comment!

Answer (score 0):

change `innerHTML == ""` to `innerHTML = ""`